# Input string. Associate index to each character in string for a dictionary

Tags: python

I am asking the user to enter a string. I am ultimately trying to pass the string to a dictionary, where the the index of each character  is associated with each character in the string.
Ex: Input = CSC120

What I have done so far is entered a string and passed it to a set. The issue is that when I pass it to a set, it passes in : {'1', '2', 'C', '0', 'S'}. It is out of order. I was thinking I would be able to correlate the string to an index once it was passed to the set, but it is out of order and does not duplicate the 'C'. 
The plan was to have 2 sets and link them in a dictionary. I am stuck at trying to get the string to be correctly passed to the set.

```
d = {}
set1 = set()
string1 = input("Enter a string:").upper()
for i in string1:
    set1.add(i)
print(set1)
```

Ultimately the results I am trying to achieve is:
d = { 0:'C', 1:'S', 2:'C', 3:'1', 4:'2', 5:'0'}

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a [dictionary display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) (aka comprehension):

```
Input = 'CSC120'

d = {i: c for i, c in enumerate(Input)}

print(d)  # -> {0: 'C', 1: 'S', 2: 'C', 3: '1', 4: '2', 5: '0'}
```

However, it can be done with even less code (and likely more quickly), by passing the `dict` constructor the an enumeration of the characters in the string (as helpfully pointed-out by @coldspeed in a comment):

```
d = dict(enumerate(Input))
```

Here's the documentation for the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

Comment: You could directly call `dict` on `enumerate`: `dict(enumerate(Input))`, also, I have never seen dict comprehensions referred to as "dictionary displays" before.

Comment: @coldspeed: Yep, that would be more succinct. "Dictionary display" is what the online documentation calls them (which makes it hard to find if you don't know this). Personally, I think most folks call them comprehensions (and the docs do, too, in the second to last paragraph).

Comment: awesome! Thank you. I had not learned about the enumerate function yet. @martineau

Comment: @coldspeed: The docs also call list comprehensions "[list displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays)". I think it has something to do with logic and/or mathematical set notation (see [Comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehension) on wikipedia.